# Can you borrow shares from broker to cover naked call?

Tags: options, call-options, put-options

If I sold a naked call, and the buyer exercises it. Can I borrow the shares from the broker to fulfil it?

Comment: Depends probably on you broker! Also, he might not have them either - not every broker has every obscure share handy.

Answer (score 1):

The broker will automatically borrow the shares from another one of its accounts  (or from another broker) if it is borrowable and you have the margin to support the short share position because of the incentive of receiving the borrow rate.